# C++ Equivalent of .split()

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to split a  string into an array of strings and I need to split them whenever a `','` is encountered.

In Java, we can use:-

```
String[] splitArray = input.split(",");
```

Is there any such a feature in C++ or I'll have to stick with the traditional way of doing this using a loop?

The solutions provided at a similar Ques. at StackOverflow Do not work for any delimiter other than space.

Answer (score -3):

strtok() does what you want: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

From the example:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This works for C prgramming, but in my case I've used
#include <string> ,rather than #include<cstring>/#include<string.h> and it takes String as
string name="My name"; 
The above mentioned function won't work here.

Comment: All you have done is provide a plagiarized C answer to a C++ question.  This is not a good answer IMHO.

Comment: It works fine with <string>? What exactly is your problem when you say the function won't work? It's completely valid C++ code and works fine here.

Comment: Just because It can compile in C++ does not mean it is C++.  If it compiles in a C compiler then it is C code not C++ code.

Comment: strtok is a function defined in string.h .. it won't work if I've used #include<string>